# Reconsider the three-day edit-ban

Tags: discussion

Why have I been edit-banned for 3 days? I believe I didn't violate anything. My recent questions, not a lot of them, didn't attract much attention but didn't have a negative score either (at the time of this writing). I believe to be mistargetted by this rule and, since I'm unlikely to be alone in that, I suggest revisiting the way the measure is applied

Comment: I believe you posted this on the wrong forum. I see no no edit-ban on you here. You've also posted no questions or answers either, so I think your issue must be with one of the other groups you frequent.

Comment: @CareyGregory https://ibb.co/8Y2Wy1x

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I looked at your profile here (meta), not the main site. You don't have an edit-ban, you have a question-ban. That wasn't imposed by me or any of the other mods. It was imposed by the system. The problem is you've had a number of questions closed and downvoted. I would recommend paying attention to the close notices on those questions and understanding why they were closed. The system is telling you it thinks you're serially posting low quality questions so it's imposing a pause.

Comment: @CareyGregory None of my two recent questions were downvoted or closed

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th carefully. Nothing more anyone here can do for you. I'm guessing you have some deleted questions with score <=0. Your recent questions don't have any upvotes, either, and the system has imposed a limit on how often you can ask questions due to previous question scores.

Comment: @BryanKrause No, I don't

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing we (MedSci mods) can do to undo this, nor can we change the algorithm the system uses. You could take it up with the Community Moderation team (CM) by clicking the "Contact" link at the bottom of the page. Or you could suggest raising the limit on the main SE meta page.

It's possible the limit could be modified for MedSci, but doing that would require the CM team. I also expect they would want to see a lot of convincing reasoning and support for doing so here in this meta, and I doubt that's going to happen. It's just not an issue that comes up often and so most people would see no reason to change it.